# On the eclipse welcome page, is it possible to link to resources located in a different plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am working on an eclipse RCP application. In the main (app) plugin I have defined a welcome or intro page. This is an XHTML file containing links to interesting resources.

There is a separate help plugin which contains the help in html and also as a PDF.

Is it possible to link from the welcome page in the app plugin to the PDF in the help plugin? I was thinking of something like this (but it didn't work)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="shared.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="root.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body> 
    <h1>Welcome to the Test Framework</h1>
    <div class="page-style">
    <div id="content">  

    <!-- app plugin -->
    <a href="presentation.pdf">
        <img border="0" src="file_powerpoint.png" alt="Presentation" />Präsentation</a>

    <!-- help plugin -->
    <a href="platform:/com.acme.atf.help/pdf/handbook_de.pdf">
        <img border="0" src="file_pdf.png" alt="Handbuch" />Handbuch</a>
    </div> 
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Look at the `org.eclipse.ui.intro.configExtension` and `org.eclipse.help.contentExtension` extension points

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your XHTML page as a config extension at your plugin.

Add the extension at the plugin.xml:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.intro.configExtension">
    <configExtension
        configId="org.eclipse.ui.intro.universalConfig"
        content="path/yourFile.xhtml" />

</extension>
```

Then, add it to the welcome page (via editing configuration, or using the Help/Welcome/Customize menu).

Link: [A short tutorial on this topic](http://www.eclipse-tips.com/tutorials/40-a-short-tutorial-on-introwelcome)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use command to open some resource (you will implement opening of the resource in handler):

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
        <command
                defaultHandler="yourHandler"
                id="openResource">
        </command>
</extension>
```

and then execute the command in xml file where you have welcome page content:

```
<introContent>
<extensionContent id="openPdf" style="css/welcome.css"
    name="SomeName" path="overview/@">
    <group style-id="content-group" id="overview-default-group">
        <link label="Open PDF"
            url='http://org.eclipse.ui.intro/execute?command=openResource'
            id="introLink" style-id="content-link">
            <text>Open PDF resource</text>
        </link>
    </group>
</extensionContent>
```